# My background is not showing up in render (Render Properties > Film > Transparent is checked)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image: Help]

I checked Film > Transparent, since many questions on here with the same problem have a solution that says to check film > transparent, but in my final render I cannot figure out how to make my background show up. I even tried connecting an image background node instead (not connected now) but that didn't work either. I'm stuck right now, and I'm pretty sure I followed Blender Guru's tutorial decently close. Please help

Comment: Film > Transparent should be **unchecked**, not checked to show a HDRI background.